# How to add chapter title and page number on a blank page?

Tags: blank-page

I am working on a report where there is a blank page at the end of a chapter. The blank page contains the current chapter title and page number at the top of the page like this:

[image: empty page]

How can I implement this?

Comment: The best solution depends on several factors, e.g., the class you are using and whether the blank page should be a left or a right one. So please show us a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that reproduces your problem and give us some more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default for `book` with `twoside` (default) if the last page of a chapter ends on a right (odd) page:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}% used for demonstration only

\begin{document}
\chapter{This is the first chapter}
\blindtext% used for demonstration only

\chapter{This is the second chapter}
\blindtext% used for demonstration only

\blinddocument% used for demonstration only
% Here we will not have a blank page, because the chapter ends on left (even) side
\blinddocument% used for demonstration only
\end{document}
```

or for `report` with explicit `twoside`, `openright` and page style `headings`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{report}% options needed for the blank left pages before a new chapter on a right page

\usepackage{blindtext}% used for demonstration only
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}% used for demonstration only
\chapter{This is the first chapter}
\blindtext% used for demonstration only

\chapter{This is the second chapter}
\blindtext% used for demonstration only

\blinddocument% used for demonstration only
\end{document}
```

For single-sided documents it wouldn't make sense.

Or to use another demonstration file with class `book` and a chapter named »chap_name« with five sections followed by a blank page and another chapter:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% used for demonstration only

\begin{document}
\chapter{chap\_name}
\lipsum[1]% used for demonstration only

\section{First Section}
\lipsum[2]% used for demonstration only

\section{Second Section}
\lipsum[3]% used for demonstration only

\section{Third Section}
\lipsum[4]% used for demonstration only

\section{Fourth Section}
\lipsum[5-10]% used for demonstration only

\section{Fifth Section}
Next page will be blank but with running head.

\chapter{This is the second chapter}
\lipsum[6]% used for demonstration only

\end{document}
```

or same with class `report`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{report}% options are need for the empty page before the second chapter
\usepackage{lipsum}% used for demonstration only

\pagestyle{headings}% needed to have automatic running heads (default of report would be page style plain that shows only page numbers)

\begin{document}
\chapter{chap\_name}
\lipsum[1]% used for demonstration only

\section{First Section}
\lipsum[2]% used for demonstration only

\section{Second Section}
\lipsum[3]% used for demonstration only

\section{Third Section}
\lipsum[4]% used for demonstration only

\section{Fourth Section}
\lipsum[5-10]% used for demonstration only

\section{Fifth Section}
Next page will be blank but with running head.

\chapter{This is the second chapter}
\lipsum[6]% used for demonstration only

\end{document}
```

both results in (only page 2–5 shown):

[image][image]

Comment: I have many sections in a chapter. So after \chapter{chap_name} there are some \section also. Should I include \blindtext after it?

Comment: @sphoenix `\blindtext` is only dummy text for examples. You do not need it for real documents. See the manual of package `blindtext` for more information. If you are using class `report` (as in your first question), you just need to change the options as shown in my second example.

Comment: The command is also generating title on some pages which aren't blank. It is also generating garbage text at the end of every chapter just before the blank page.

Comment: @sphoenix: Did you understand, that using package `blindtext` and commands `\blindtext` and `\blinddocument` is *not* part of the solution but has been done only to show you a short compilable example? The solution is the usage of either the correct class or the correct options of a given class.

Comment: Sir, I have a \chapter{chap_one} and under that chapter 5 sections. \section.
Then I needed a blank page before starting the new chapter. So I did \afterpage{\null\newpage} and then I wrote \blindtext. And then I started the new chapter \chapter{chap_two}.
I didn't understand properly what you tried to say by the phrase "documentation only".

Comment: @sphoenix: I do not use the phrase "documentation only". And please read the comment below your question. It would be much easier to help you, if you would do what you have been told. And please read the [`blindtext` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/blindtext/blindtext.pdf) to understand why I'm using it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57349/discussion-between-sphoenix-and-schweinebacke).

Comment: I actually didn't see the comment below my question and should've gone through the documentation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This tex code displays an empty page with the chapter header and page number:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title}
Some text
\newpage\phantom{}

\chapter{Second chapter}
Some text

\end{document}
```

What did you try that did not work?

Comment: I tried:
\chapter{chap_name1}
\section
\newpage\phantom{}
\chapter{Second chapter}
It does show a blank page but doesn't show any title or page number on top of the page.